# Getting 403 Error on Calling GET Rest API

Tags: php, curl, get, php-curl

As per API Documentation, the Curl is:

```
curl -X GET "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByPin?pincode=110001&date=31-03-2021" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Accept-Language: hi_IN"
```

My PHP Script:

```
$url='https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByPin?pincode='.$pincode.'&date='.$tomorrow;
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'accept: application/json',
    'Accept-Language: hi_IN'
]);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$curl_error = curl_errno($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response . PHP_EOL;
```

When I run my PHP Script, I'm getting this 403 Error:
[image]

Is there anything wrong with my PHP Script?

Comment: I suggest you try again later, or contact the app or website owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine

```
<?php

    $pincode = "110001";
    $tomorrow = "31-03-2021";
    
    $url='https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByPin?pincode='.$pincode.'&date='.$tomorrow;
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'accept: application/json',
        'Accept-Language: hi_IN'
    ]);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $curl_error = curl_errno($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response . PHP_EOL;
```

Got this..

```
{
  "centers": [
    
  ]
}
```